# Switching from Wilson ORMapper, what are my best alternatives?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

We're currently using Wilson ORMapper with our asp.net 2.0 website against an Oracle db and we're having some issues that is making us look into an alternative ormapper.  I know there is nhibernate but are there any other we should look into for our environment (.net and oracle db) or has nhibernate become the industry leader and therefore we don't need to look any further.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want more .NET ORM options, you likely need to upgrade your website to .NET 3.5 or 4.0.  NHibernate is just fine though.

Answer (score 3):

NHibernate. You don't need to look any further.

We also migrated an app. from Wilson ORMapper (WORM) to NHibernate and have been very happy with the results.